# R, Aggregate Summing Across All Values in Reference Column (Instead of Just One)

Tags: r, aggregate, average, mean

I've tried several different methods to get a summary table of averages by half hour, similar to an average pivot table. My preferred method is with aggregate, but I seem to get nothing but an average for the top row.

Data is as shown in the link, where the Group and the Messages can be ignored.
[See below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGdSP.png)

The code I'm using is...

```
Data <- read_csv("P:/Book3.csv", col_types = cols(Date = col_date(format = "%m/%d/%Y"), 
                                                  Time = col_time(format = "%H:%M:%S")))
View(Data)

class(Data)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

aggregate(Data[, 3:4], list(Data$Time), mean)

   Group.1    Calls Estimated_Calls
1 08:30:00 15.38889        14.55556
```

You'll notice the single line, but ideally the output would have averages for every time.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: We can use `summarise_all`, `summarise_at`, or `summarise_if` with `group_by` to aggregate the data from `dplyr`. If you can share the `Book3.csv`, we can probably demonstrate how to do this.

Comment: It's always better to include your data instead of a picture of the data.  Try `dput(Data)` and edit your question to include the output of that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use the `dplyr` library for problems of this sort:

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% group_by(Time) %>% 
    summarise(Mean_Calls = mean(Calls), Mean_Est_Calls = mean(Estimated_Calls))
```

I find the pipe `%>%` makes code easier to read (once you get used to it).  This is a feature of the `dplyr` library.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `data.table` for summary operations like this:

```
setDT(Data)

Data[, .(Mean_Calls = mean(Calls), Mean_Est_Calls = mean(Estimated_Calls)),
    by=.(Group, Time)]
```

This will group by Group and Time, meaning you'll have one row for each combination of Group and Time.

With dummy data (used 3 "hours" for time; also changed `by` to `keyby` to sort):

```
set.seed(48)

df1 <- data.table(Group = sample(LETTERS[1:3],10,T),
 Time = sample(1:3,10,T),
 Calls = sample(1:50,10,T),
 Estimated_Calls = sample(1:50,10,T))

df1[, .(Mean_Calls = mean(Calls), Mean_Est_Calls = mean(Estimated_Calls)),
        keyby=.(Group, Time)]
```

Output:

```
   Group Time Mean_Calls Mean_Est_Calls
1:     A    2   27.00000       22.00000
2:     A    3   34.66667       25.66667
3:     B    2   26.00000        6.50000
4:     B    3   20.00000        1.00000
5:     C    2   35.50000       32.00000
```

With `aggregate`:

```
df2 <- aggregate(df1[,3:4], by=with(df1,list(Group,Time)),mean)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I would have used this but have had some troubles getting the data.table package to install correctly (installs but never seems to find the function). Searching the web, this seems to be a common problem. This is great to know though!